# How to figure out the functor for cats.Parallel?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, implicit, scala-cats

Because IntelliJ does not play all that nicely with Cats, I am sometimes explicit about type parameters in my code to avoid ugly red lines. For example, if we assume this gives a red line under `IO.pure(x.toString)`,

```
List(1, 2, 3).traverse(x => IO.pure(x.toString))
```

then I can easily add the types and IntelliJ is happy:

```
List(1, 2, 3).traverse[IO, String](x => IO.pure(x.toString))
```

Now, with [`parTraverse`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/syntax/ParallelTraversableOps.html) it seems a bit more difficult because of the functor parameter:

```
List(1, 2, 3).parTraverse[IO, ???, String](x => IO.pure(x.toString)) //what is ???
```

Is there any way to figure out the type of the `F[_]` parameter here so I can please IntelliJ or is this some partial unification thing and so I'm doomed to ugliness? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [scaladoc api of cats-effects](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/?search=Parallel), and search for `Parallel` instances, it lists you just a single implicit method that produces `Parallel[IO, ???]`, namely `Parallel[IO, Par]` provided by `cats.effect.IO.ioParallel`. So, it seems that `cats.effect.IO.Par` should do the trick:

```
List(1, 2, 3).parTraverse[IO, Par, String](x => IO.pure(x.toString))
```